# how to get the touch on sprite sheet animation in cocs2d

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine

i have an animation made by sprite sheet, it is working fine but I just want to get location of the place where the user touches animated sprite ?
I know getchiledbytag method but it works fine with still sprite not animated sprite 
please help

Comment: emm... cannot understand, what do you want to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i thing you want to stop animation, then...

```
[self stopAllActions];
```